# Get latest job revision while submitting AWS batch job without specifying the exact revision number

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-batch

I am using AWSBatch Java client `com.amazonaws.services.batch (AWS SDK for Java - 1.11.483)` to submit jobs programmatically.

However, our scientists keep updating the job definition.
Every time there is a new job definition, I have to update the environment variable with the revision number to pass it to the client.
[AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/APIReference/API_SubmitJob.html) states that

> This value can be either a name:revision or the Amazon Resource Name (ARN) for the job definition.

Is there any way I can default it to the latest revision and every time I submit a BatchJob, the latest revision will get picked without even knowing the last revision?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> This value can be either a name:revision or the Amazon Resource Name (ARN) for the job definition.

Seems like AWS didn't document this properly: `revision` is optional, you can use simply use `name` instead of `name:revision` and it will get the `ACTIVE` revision of your job definition. It's also optional for Job Definition ARNs.

This also applies for `boto3` and for AWS Step Functions integration with AWS Batch, and probably all other interfaces where Job Definition name or ARN are required.

Comment: I cannot find this documentation anywhere!

Also, if there is more than one `ACTIVE` revision, is it safe to assume that the "latest" one will be picked up?

Comment: AWS Documentation is open-source, so you can submit a pull request to https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-batch-user-guide if you find the time to do so. As for your second question, can there even be more that one `ACTIVE` revision for one job definition? I assumed there can't be.

Comment: There can be. I have a few revisions that are `ACTIVE`.

Answer (score 6):

From AWS Batch [SubmitJob](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/APIReference/API_SubmitJob.html) API reference.

> **jobDefinition**
>
> The job definition used by this job. This value can be one of name,
> name:revision, or the Amazon Resource Name (ARN) for the job
> definition. If name is specified without a revision then the latest
> active revision is used.

perhaps the documentation is updated by now.

Answer (score 0):

I could not find any Java SDK function but I ended up using a bash script that fetches the latest* revision number from AWS.

```
$ aws batch describe-job-definitions  --job-definition-name ${full_name}  \
   --query='jobDefinitions[?status==`ACTIVE`].revision'  --output=json \
   --region=${region} | jq '.[0]'
```

(*) The `.[0]` will pick the first object from a list of active revisions, I used this because, by default, AWS Batch adds the latest revision to the top. You can set it as `.[-1]` if you want the last one.